# FindBugs: Why did I get NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF and what would be better?

Tags: java, findbugs

with the following code I get **NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF: Method call passes null for nonnull parameter**:

```
public void calledAnywhereIDoNotCare() {
  //[...]
  //parameter could be null but shouldn't ever be by logic
  method(parameter); //FindBugs says the problem is here
  //[...]
}

public final ReturnType method(final ParameterType parameter) {
  //this method do nothing but simply call anotherMethod()
  return anotherMethod(parameter, false);
}

public final ReturnType anotherMethod(final ParameterType parameter, boolean boolParam) {
  if (parameter == null) {
    //just in case logic is wrong
    throw new NullPointerException("I know it shouldn't be null by logic, but it is null!");
  }
  //do something very usefull
  //[...]
}
```

So, my question is: Why did I get this NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF and what changes would be better?
Did I get this because of declaring the parameter final? Or because of not catching the NullPointerException? I don't want to catch it, it should be catched somewhere out there. Maybe I should declare throwing NullPointerException in calledAnywhereIDoNotCare()?

Thank you for your help.
TARL

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you write that the parameter "could" be null but never will because of the program logic. FindBugs doesn't know/understand the logic. The best way would be to let FindBugs ignore the NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF in this method using the edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings annotation. See http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html

Comment: Ok, suppressing the warning is a posibility. But why is the parameter in my method a nonnull parameter for findbugs anyway?

Comment: Sadly FindBugs isn't very smart. Maybe you can post the code of calledAnywhereIDoNotCare(). But probably it simple cannot detect the logic which prevents null and so it warns you. An alternative to supressing the warning is add code which "handles" the never existing null value. But i would consider that bad practice.

Comment: Or maybe it's so smart that it can determine that you throw an NPE if a null value is passed. See what happens when you just print a message if the value is parameter is null in anotherMethod?